# Populate TableView in main UI thread after calling WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Inside **Xamarin (C#)**, I have a **WCF service** generated with **SlSvcUtil.exe** that is called with a **BasicHttpBinding**. That all works. All I do is register a callback, call the service, and wait for the data.

This part doesn't really matter, but we had to wrap our objects to get **WCF** to play nice. So I created a function that wraps the **WCF** call and returns a list of our unwrapped objects. That all works too.

Problem is, I'm trying to get this to work from inside the **TableViewController** or inside the **TableViewSource**. If all my callback does is something like the following, it works:

```
//Inside TableViewSource
private void Callback(List<MyObject> objects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Count; i++) {
        _items.Add(objects[i]);
    }
}
```

However, I still need to call `TableView.ReloadData()`. Calling this fails because I'm not on the main UI thread. There is a `TableView.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(NSAction action)` function, but an **NSAction** cannot take parameters, so I can't return my list.

I also tried posting a notification, but that's failing for the same reason (probably because I'm posting from inside the callback):

```
//Inside TableViewController
private void PropertyChanged(NSNotification notification) {
    TableView.ReloadData();
    // or TableView.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => TableView.ReloadData());
}

//Inside TableViewSource
private void Callback(List<MyObject> objects) {
    //work here
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("Objects", this);
}
```

How can I pass my list to the main UI thread and populate my **TableView**? I must be missing something simple here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I just figured it out. [Threading in Xamarin is described here.](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/threading/)

All I had to do was:

```
//Inside TableViewController
private void Callback(List<MyObject> objects) {
    InvokeOnMainThread(() => {
        ((MyTableViewSource)TableView.Source).AddObjects(objects);
        TableView.ReloadData();
    });
}
```

`InvokeOnMainThread` is defined on `NSObject`, so you can just call it instead of using `TableView.InvokeOnMainThread` like I was trying before.